# Find the first number in a string, could be 1,11,111

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am looping through file names with such pattern `name_name-number-name_name.txt`

I need to extract the `number`.

For example,

- from `xxx_xx-111-ssadas22` I would get `111`.
- from `xxx_xx-11-sadaesdwsq4443fsd2` I would get `11`

Currently using this but it falls short when there is a number in the name. Also tried a regex but am bad at it.

```
Function FirstDigit(strData As String) As Integer
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim REMatches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
         .Pattern = "(^|\\s)([0-100]+)($|\\s)"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    FirstDigit = REMatches.item(0)
End Function
```

any idea ?

Comment: and how do i get only 111 from the -111- ?

Comment: ok i meant if i used regex "-([0-9]+)-" like the deleted comment suggested

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Function FirstDigit(strData As String) As Integer
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim REMatches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
         .Pattern = "\b[^_\s]+_[^-\s]+-(\d+)-[^\.\s]+\.txt\b"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    If REMatches.Count > 0 Then
        FirstDigit = REMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
    Else
        FirstDigit = -1     '' or whatever you want to output when there is no match
    End If
End Function
```

Test:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print FirstDigit("xxx_xx-1-ssadas22.txt")     '' Returns 1
    Debug.Print FirstDigit("xxx_xx-11-ssadas22.txt")    '' Returns 11
    Debug.Print FirstDigit("xxx_xx-111-ssadas22.txt")   '' Returns 111
    Debug.Print FirstDigit("xxx_xx-asasa-ssadas22.txt") '' Returns -1 (no match)
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Much better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Function FirstDigit(strData As String) As Integer
    FirstDigit = 0
    ary = Split(strData, "-")
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        If IsNumeric(ary(i)) Then
            FirstDigit = CInt(ary(i))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of the string remains the same then this works for me

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print FirstDigit("xxx_xx-1-ssadas22")
    Debug.Print FirstDigit("xxx_xx-11-ssadas22")
    Debug.Print FirstDigit("xxx_xx-111-ssadas22")
End Sub

Function FirstDigit(strData As String) As Integer
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim REMatches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
         .Pattern = "(\-([^-]+)\-)"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    FirstDigit = Abs(Val(REMatches.Item(0)))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, and doesn't require your filenames to fit any particular pattern. For any input string it will return the first (whole) number i.e. the first sequence of consecutive digit characters.

```
Function GetFirstNumber(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strFirstNumber As String
    Dim thisChar As String
    Dim foundNumberStart As Boolean
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        thisChar = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If thisChar Like "[0-9]" Then
            foundNumberStart = True
            strFirstNumber = strFirstNumber & thisChar
        ElseIf foundNumberStart Then
            Exit For 'Number finished.
        End If
    Next i
    GetFirstNumber = strFirstNumber
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
?GetFirstNumber(" xxx_xx-111-ssadas22")
111 
?GetFirstNumber("xxx_xx-11-sadaesdwsq4443fsd2")
11 
?GetFirstNumber("  kjhsdfg WWWAAHHH!*666zombiesarecoming9827365498#%")
666
```